# Software for lowering the colors in PNG-24 files

Tags: compression, png

I am searching for a software that will allow me to reduce the number of colors for PNG-24 transparent (as in photoshop) files. Photoshop doesn't allow me any control over the amount of colors the PNG is saved, having this kind of software/plugin would be great.

Comment: ... i'm afraid you might be out of luck on this one. If you're thinking in terms of reducing the size of the file by limiting colors that won't happen. I think there are some ways / utilities to optimize png sizes, but color reduction 'gif-style' isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two tools:

- [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) which creates 256-color PNGs **with alpha channel**. That greatly reduces file sizes (60-70%). In latest versions it may have better quality and smaller file size than Photoshop's Save For Web (even for images without alpha).
- [mediancut posterizer](https://github.com/pornel/mediancut-posterizer) reduces number of unique colors in 24/32-bit PNG files. This can reduce file sizes by 20-30%, and again is smarter than posterizing colors in Photoshop as it also posterizes alpha channel and is smarter about selecting posterization levels.

Both of those programs have a GUI: [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com).

Answer (score 1):

You could use ImageMagick's convert application with the -color flag.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=fv5ffdto8nt4revt54g3ba7ne7#colors

i.e: `convert something.png -color 256`

Comment: Thanks, but is their anything like a visual GUI instead of command line?

Comment: You could use the gimp http://www.gimp.org/windows/ which is a bit more geeky than Photoshop. But many would argue that their UI is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use [RIOT](https://riot-optimizer.com/), it allows you to select different algorithms to compress the image, select the number of colors you want while maintaining the alpha channel of a PNG file. On each change you do you can see the resultant image with the reductions you selected.

The application also has one option to set the filesize you need and it will do the optimizations needed to get that size of image.

The aplication it's fully FREE